# display php variable from upload.php into index.html

Tags: php, html

I want to display the $msg_ok / $msg_nok variable from the separat upload.php file into the index.html. How can i do that? Thx.

```
     <?php
// Moves uploaded file to directory
$targetPath = "uploads/" . basename($_FILES["inpFile"]["name"]);
$msg_ok = "ok File upload successfull.\n";
$msg_nok = " nok Opps something went wrong!\n";

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['inpFile']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)) {
    echo $msg_ok;
} else {
    echo $msg_nok;
}
echo 'More debugging information:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Redirect with `header("Location: index.php?message=" . urlencode($msg_ok));` And then in in index.php use `$_GET['message']`.

Comment: Ok thats my html :```<p><?php
        echo $_GET['message'];
        ?></p>``` the message will not display, but i can see it in Inspect: ```<p class="php">ok File upload successfull.
</p>```  but why?

Answer (score 0):

Call the php file in javascript using [Ajax](https://Call%20the%20file%20from%20javascript%20using%20ajax%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) from index.html  and insert the returned value in a html element using [one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) ( of many ) method to modify the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)